# WPF custom usercontrol property binding always default value

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

So I found several answers but none with my specific problem. In code it looks like this:

**UserControl**

```
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(NiceTextBox), new PropertyMetadata("default"));

public MyUserControl() {
    InitializeComponent();
    var whatIsMyText = Text;
}
```

**XAML**

```
<customControl:MyUserControl ... Text="sometext" />
```

The `whatIsMyText` does not have `"sometext"` inside but `"default"`. I am sure this is because of the timing of the initialization and actually setting the property data that is written inside of the xaml. But how do I do it correctly?

Comment: The Text property is set after the constructor has finished. You have to register a PropertyChangedCallback by PropertyMetadata to get notified about changes of the property's value.

Comment: So basically there is no way to have the latest value already inside the constructor?

Comment: @MuhKuh How do you expect XAML to set a property value on an object that hasn't been constructed yet?

Comment: yes, doesn't make sense. I created a PropertyChangedCallback handler and set the value after initialization.